# How To 301 Redirect 40k pages without htaccess

Tags: redirect

I know how to redirect a page to other page with htaccess but **how to redirect 40k pages without htaccess**? I have read from other source, the maximum limit for htaccess is about 1500 line and larger than that will make my web slow.

example, i have:

```
mysite/book/titlepage1
mysite/book/titlepage2
mysite/book/titlepage3
mysite/book/titlepage4
:
:
mysite/book/titlepage50K
```

I need redirect for example:

```
mysite/book/titlepage10
mysite/book/titlepage11
mysite/book/titlepage12
mysite/book/titlepage13
:
:
mysite/book/titlepage40k
```

to mysite2.com

Comment: Well, depending on how exactly you want to redirect, you could have a single `.htaccess` line redirecting all of those pages. You’ll need to add more information to your question about what kind of redirection is taking place, e.g. are you just trying to redirect `/old_url.php?id=123` to `/new_url.php?id=123`, do you need to fetch things from a database to redirect e.g. `article.cgi?id=123` to `articles/dewey-defeats-truman`, etc.

Comment: I have added the detail, please check, Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You could make a php code that receives the URL that the user requests and redirects to the right page. If you use PHP, then the server will process the request, and not the computer of the user.